# Create Simplified query for nested data in one table (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have table like:

```
Steps
 - id
 - name
 - parendId
```

`parentId` is pointing on `id` in same table.

Main problem is because I have 3 level of nesting...

I want output like this:

```
step: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'step 1'
    childs: [
        {
            id: 2
            name: 'child lvl 1',
            childs: [
               {
                  id: 3,
                  name: 'child lvl 2'
                  childs: [...]
               }, ...
            ]
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

So in my app I have something like this:

```
var parents =  _apiDbContext.StepResult
               .ToList();

foreach (var parent in parents) {
    var childs = _apiDbContext.StepResult
               .Where(s => s.StepParent == parent.Id)
               .ToList();

    foreach (var child in childs) {
         var childsLvl2 = _apiDbContext.StepResult
               .Where(s => s.StepParent == child.Id)
               .ToList();

         // ... One more level
    }
}
```

This is minimal code for example if I make some mistakes please let me know.

So is possible to do this things with one query or some "magic" in .net core.

This works fine but is killing performance... So any advice will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following recursive code that will work with any number of levels

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication139
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tree root = new Tree();
            int rootId = 0;
            GetRecursive(rootId, root);
        }
        static void GetRecursive(int parentId, Tree parent)
        {
            foreach(Step step in steps.Where(x => x.id == parentId))
            {
                parent.step = step;
                if (parent.children == null) parent.children = new List<Tree>();
                Tree child = new Tree();
                parent.children.Add(child);
                GetRecursive(step.id, child);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Step
    {
       public int id { get;set;}
       public string name { get;set;}
       public int parendId { get; set; }
    }
    public class Tree
    {
        public List<Tree> children { get; set; }
        public Step step { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would select all of the rows at once into a flat data structure, and then load it into your desired tree structure. This will give you a good idea on how to accomplish this:

```
//declare a class to hold your data
public class step
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? parentId { get; set; }
    public List<step> childs { get; set; }
}

public void loadSteps()
{
    var steps = new List<step>();

    //instead of doing this load from your db
    steps.Add(new step { id = 1, name = "t1", parentId = null });
    steps.Add(new step { id = 2, name = "t2", parentId = 1 });
    steps.Add(new step { id = 3, name = "t3", parentId = 2 });
    steps.Add(new step { id = 4, name = "t4", parentId = 1 });
    steps.Add(new step { id = 5, name = "t5", parentId = 1 });
    steps.Add(new step { id = 6, name = "t6", parentId = null });
    steps.Add(new step { id = 7, name = "t7", parentId = 6 });

    //build the tree from the flat data
    var tree = BuildTree(steps);
}

//build the tree using linq (this could also be done with a queue or recursion
static List<step> BuildTree(List<step> items)
{
    items.ForEach(i => i.childs = items.Where(ch => ch.parentId == i.id).ToList());
    return items.Where(i => i.parentId == null).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your steps tree with single database query:

```
var dbList = _apiDbContext.StepResult
               .ToList();

List<Steps> steps = dbList.Where(x => x.parentID == null).Select(x => new Steps { id = x.id, name = x.name }).ToList();
steps.ForEach(x => Sample(x, dbList));
```

```
public class Steps
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Steps> childs { get; set; }
}
```

```
public void Sample(Steps step, List<DbSteps> dbList)
{
    var childs = dbList.Where(x => x.parentID == step.id);
    if (!childs.Any())
        return;

    step.childs = childs.Select(x => new Steps { id = x.id, name = x.name }).ToList();
    step.childs.ForEach(x => Sample(x, dbList));
}
```